# ContentProvider Update

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

Is there a way to do the following query using the ContentProvider ?

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET ColumnName=ColumnName + 1 
WHERE id=1
```

I know I could execute this as a rawQuery but I'd like to know how many rows have been affected. Moreover, the execSQL method says :

> It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et al, when possible.

However, I couldn't find any way to use the update method from my ContentProvider to do it.

Comment: use update() to update

Comment: I know how to update the values by replacing them, but I don't know how to do some operations on them like an increment

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...; // get your database
String sql = "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = columnName + 1 WHERE id = 1";
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
int affected = statement.executeUpdateDelete();
statement.close();
```

*(begin edit)*

You could define a URI that when passed to `update` simply ignores the `ContentValues` argument and executes the code above.

*(end edit)*

The only other way I can think of to do this through a ContentProvider would be to implement the [`call`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#call%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method in your ContentProvider and redirect to another method based on what gets passed in. Then you would use [`ContentResolver.call(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#call%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and give it a Bundle with necessary information.

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm sure it would do the tricks but, unfortunately, this call requires API level 11 and I want my app to be able to run on lower versions. Thank you anyway

Comment: Why does it need to run on lower versions? Gingerbread and below represent less than 20% of devices and that number is dwindling.

Comment: On a side note, you can also pass this information in a cursor. Ether with a MatrixCursor that holds the result or within a default cursor by utilizing the 'getExtras' and 'setExtras' methods.

Comment: @GPuschka There's no point returning a `Cursor` just to include an integer in its extras. Updates don't return Cursors anyway, and there's no reason to do a query in addition to the update.